# usbview error on startup

Tags: usb

I was trying to use the `usbview` program when I got this message error message after trying to start the program:

```
Verify that you have USB compiled into your kernel, 
have the USB core modules loaded, and have the 
usbdevfs filesystem mounted.
```

After this its more or less up to the user so I really don't know what to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to run the program as root.

In a text terminal/shell, use:

`sudo usbview`

(You need to enter your password)

If you need a GUI command, use:

`gksu usbview`

The full error message in that error dialog window is:

```
Can not open the file /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices

 Verify that you have USB compiled into your kernel, 
 have the USB core modules loaded, and have the 
 usbdevfs filesystem mounted.
```

It lists various possible cases of the problem - except the most common one - that is confusing.
It made me also think that it's probably not the problem, because I would expect it in the list. Actually, one could see the message as a minor bug.